# Stochastic integrals

Tags: probability, statistics

It is not true that if the mean of a random variable is 0 and it's. Variance is t-s, then it has a normal distribution  with mean zero and variance t-s !!!!!!

Attempted; 
To be is only true if our random variable Is continuos . Please for some clearification thanks

Comment: It's not true in general, and has nothing to do with stochastic integrals, even if we assume the random variable is continuous

Comment: Please for any opinion sir and example thanks

Comment: For an example take a random variable with uniform distribution on $[-r, r]$, $r>0$. It's an absolutely continuous random variable with mean $0$ and variance $r^2/3$

Comment: Ok sir it true. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Counter example:

Let $X_t \sim \mathcal{U}(\ [-\sqrt{3(T-t)},\sqrt{3(T-t)}]\ )$

$\forall t < T:$

- $Var[X_t]=T-t $
- $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=0$

The process is continuous. $\forall t < T,\ X_t$  is a continuous random variable but is not normal (it has uniform distribution!).

The only way for a r.v. to be a normal r.v. is to have normal law, indipendently to its mean and variance. (Quite tautological, but that's it!).

Comment: Clearification done thanks Sir.